# Sharepoint2013 get URL of video file from asset library using Rest\Jsom

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way we can get the URL of the video file uploaded to SharePoint2013 asset library using JSOM or REST?

I tried to look at the Asset library "Video" Content type and I dint find any site column which stores the URL of the uploaded video file.

Thanks,

Comment: how did you uploaded vedio it?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, in order to retrieve videos from Assets library in SharePoint 2013, it is important to understand how videos are organized.

### How are videos organized?

According to [Enhanced Video Experience in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.office.com/2013/03/08/enhanced-video-experience-in-sharepoint-2013/):

> Videos are organized in a manner similar to document sets, which is a
>   group of related documents that can be created in a single step and
>   managed as one entity. To learn more about document sets, see
>   [Introduction to document sets](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx). SharePoint creates a stub (think
>   of it as a folder) to hold a video and all the related contents, such
>   as user-defined properties, thumbnails, video renditions, and other
>   documents related to the video. When you upload a video file,
>   SharePoint automatically creates this stub for that video. You can
>   imagine the video set to be the encapsulation of everything related to
>   that video.

Suppose `Wildlife_512kb.mp4` file have to be uploaded into Assets library.

Then the following folder structure with content will be generated after file uploading into Assets library 
[image]

The actual video file will be stored under:

```
<ListUrl>/<VideoSet>/<FileName>
```

where `VideoSet` (folder container) name will be set to the file name without extension.

### Examples

How to retrieve video file Url in Assets library via JSOM

```
function getAssetFileUrl(listTitle,videoFileName,success,error) {

  var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);   
  context.load(list,'RootFolder');

  context.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
      var videoSetName = videoFileName.substring(0,videoFileName.lastIndexOf(".")); 
      var videoFileUrl = list.get_rootFolder().get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/" + videoSetName + "/" + videoFileName;
      success(videoFileUrl);
   }, 
   error
);

}
```

Usage

```
var listTitle = 'Assets';
var videoFileName = 'Wildlife_512kb.mp4';
getAssetFileUrl(listTitle,videoFileName,
   function(fileUrl) {
      console.log(fileUrl);   
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());    
   });
```

### References

[Enhanced Video Experience in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.office.com/2013/03/08/enhanced-video-experience-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: This is absolutely  great.. but how to get all the videos from asset library if we don't know the file name. Eg: I want to show the all videos thumbnail.. if user clicks on thumbnail then particular video should get play.. How to achieve this?

Comment: @Mihir did you ever find the solution? Above approach wont be helpful as I wont be knowing file names in advance